# How to get the correct INavigationService instance on resolving a type manually in Prism application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, prism

It seems that when I resolve a type manually and request the `INavigationService` in it a different instance is injected than the one being used everywhere else.

To clearify my use-case here are excerpts from the relevant files. As you can see when resolving the type `SampleProcess` the `INavigationService` will be injected but the instance is different to the one that I got in `ProcessService`. (Which btw is the correct instance, that can be used for navigation. The one injected in `SampleProcess` cannot be used for navigating.)

Any ideas why this is happening and more importantely how I can get the correct instance of `INavigationService` be injected into `SampleProcess`. Yes, I could provide it for example by passing it in with a method, but that's not so pretty.

App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ProcessService>();
    containerRegistry.Register<Processes.SampleProcess>();
}
```

ProcessService.cs

```
public class ProcessService
{
    private readonly IContainer container;
    private readonly INavigationService navigationService;

    public ProcessService(IContainer container, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public void ExecuteProcess(ProcessEnum processEnumValue)
    {
        Type processType = processEnumValue switch
        {
            ProcessEnum.SampleProcess => typeof(Processes.SampleProcess),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
        };

        var process = App.Current.Container.Resolve(processType) as IProcess;

        bool test = process.CheckNavigationService(navigationService); // will return false
    }
}
```

SampleProcess.cs

```
public class SampleProcess : IProcess
{
    private readonly INavigationService navigationService;

    public SampleProcess(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public bool CheckNavigationService(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        return this.navigationService == navigationService;
    }
}
```

Comment: "The one injected in SampleProcess cannot be used for navigating." - Why?

Comment: Don't know, it seems to be another `INavigationService` instance of some sort. Either way when I use it with `navigationService.NavigateAsync([...])` nothing happens. Also when comparing the two instances I found out, that the correct one states that the current page is the one that I am currently on and the wrong one says the current page is a `default(Xamarin.Forms.Page)` (guessing it's `default` cause it does not contain any data).

Comment: Could you share the INavigationService class code? Is there a way you could share your github repo

Comment: you can use `var result = navigationService.NavigateAsync([...]) ` to have more info on what's the problem, I took a look at the [Prism Docs](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/registering-types.html) about the Registering Types, you can check if your service has been injected like this: `bool IsImplemented = containerRegistry.IsRegistered<SomeService>();`

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want is a single instance of `INavigationService`, so you need to register it as a singleton

Comment: @Saamer the code can be found here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Forms/Prism.Forms/Navigation/PageNavigationService.cs

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais I know that there's a result but the result says the call was successful even though on the app no navigation happened. Also `IsRegistered` says an instance of `INavigationService` is registered.

Comment: @MatteoUmili I don't do the registration. It is done by Prism automatically.

Comment: that's really weird, if both those checks came successful, everything should work, maybe you should create a issue in their repo, i'm wondering if this might be some path / naming convention problem? what happens if you make SampleProcess a separated class file and let prism do the registration again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding an `INavigationService` parameter to the `ExecuteProcess` method that gets called from within the viewmodel (that in fact has the correct `INavigationService` instance). Within the method I then resolve the process by doing the following:

```
var process = container.Resolve(processType, new[] { navigationService }) as IProcess;
```

This way the correct `INavigationService` instance is available within the `IProcess` instance.

As @Dan Siegel stated this could possibly be further improved by using Prism 8 and registering the `ProcessService` as a scoped service as this would eliminate the necessity to have a `INavigationService` parameter in `ExecuteProcess`.

Answer (score 1):

Navigation in Prism is based on which page you are Navigating from. For this reason the NavigationService is a transient service. It is constructed special for your ViewModel so that the instance provided for you is aware of which page it will need to Navigate from.

There are several potential solutions for your issue.

1. Don't inject the INavigationService into another service as it isn't meant to be handled that way.
2. Provide the INavigationService as a parameter that you pass to whatever service needs to use it
3. Simply make your ProcessService a transient
4. Update to Prism 8 and make your Process Service a Scoped Service as we've made a change in Prism 8 that creates a new scope each time a new page is created. This means that any Scoped or Transient services that need access to the NavigationService would be able to inject the same exact instance that is injected into the ViewModel